Will Django query database for related model if I only access the pk?
Simple question here.
I have two models "Apples" and "Bananas".
Model Apple has an FK relationship with Banana.
If I run myApple = Apple.objects.get(pk = pk) then django runs a SQL query to fetch the data.
If I want to access Banana from this "myApple" variable, then django will run another query to fetch the related object, but what if I only want to access the PK for an apple serialiser?
Will Django run another SQL query if all I'm doing is "return myApple.banana.pk"?
I could add a .select_related of course, but seems unneccesary if the PK is returned as part of the foreign key value when returning the original Apple query.


Will Django run another SQL query if all I'm doing is return myApple.banana.pk?

Yes, but the good news is, you can get the primary key without fetching, by using:
myApple.banana_id
If you define a ForeignKey named foo, you get a foo_id field as well that stores the column the ForeignKey refers to.

Excellent, thank you! And am I correct in thinking I can later use foo_id to run a foo.objects.get(pk = foo_id) if I need it? Likewise I can use this to insert the foo model object as an FK simply by referencing ID. So if I want to add banana to myFruits, I can do myFruits.objects.create(banana = myApple.banana_id)
